watchOS: userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) not getting called
I'm developing a watchOS app where I need to handle notifications. I've implemented the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods, but it seems that userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) is not being called when a notification is received. while  userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: is working perfectly.
I've checked similar questions but haven't found a solution that works for me:
userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) Contains Empty Notification - watchOSWhy is userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:) Not Fired?
Here I have attached the minimum reproducible example.
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

class NotificationManager: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    static let shared = NotificationManager()
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    /// Request notification permissions from the user.
    func requestNotificationPermission() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error requesting notification permissions: \(error)")
            } else {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                print("Notification permissions granted: \(granted)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Schedule a test notification to trigger immediately.
    func scheduleTestNotification() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Test Notification"
        content.body = "This is a test notification."
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error scheduling test notification: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Test notification scheduled.")
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Handle notification responses
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("Notification received in the background: \(response.notification.request.identifier)")
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    // Handle notification delivery while the app is in the foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("Notification received in the foreground: \(notification.request.identifier)")
        completionHandler([.sound, ])
    }
}

Here is my ContentView
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
     var notificationManager = NotificationManager.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Request Notification Permission") {
                notificationManager.requestNotificationPermission()
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button("Schedule Test Notification") {
                notificationManager.scheduleTestNotification()
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            notificationManager.requestNotificationPermission()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

The userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:) method is not being called when the notification is delivered. I've set up everything according to the documentation, but it seems to be failing to trigger.

That delegate method is only called when the user interacts with a notification. There is no delegate method that is called when a local notification is delivered to the user.

@Paulw11 Is there any possibility to achieve it with push notification didreceiveremotenotification

That method is called when a silent push notification is sent
